# Problems validating rich:calendar

Tags: java, jsf, calendar, richfaces

I am trying to validate a rich:calendar for not null input using `<rich:beanValidator />`, but i am not able to validate for null inputs.

For example in my constraits.xml file, i validate getter for calendar:

```
<getter name="dateOfBirth">

  <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Past"/> (works fine)

  <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull" /> (not work)

  <constraint annotation="org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty"/> (not work)

</getter>
```

Those last two constraint did not worked because "DateTime" data type dose not recognize them ? (first of them as far as i know is used for numeric values and second one for strings).

There is such a constraint for date time data type ? Could i validate somehow using constraints written in xml file for not null inputs ?

I am forced to used required="true" in xhtml for this kind of validation (not null) for rich:calendar (if i am using hibernate validator) ?

Please if you have an idea help me...

Regards,
Mircea

Answer (score 0):

`@NotNull`: The annotated element must not be null. Accepts any type.

Did you check whether it is really null? Because it might have been set to `new Date()` for example. Also, try if works with annotations, rather than constraints.xml (it could be a bug in beanvalidator)

Anyway, `required="true"` seems a good solution.

Comment: Hi Bozho,
 
 Thanks a lot for posting !

 I tryed using annotations written in java classes but also, the not null validation is not working.

 I have the same feeling that when rich:calendar is enabled it is initialized by default with new Date(), and this fact "tricks" not null validator ,in GUI. May be a custom validator for new Date() ( which as far as i know will be current date, but is not set on GUI for calendar , so i guess that will fail) could be another solution.

Regards

Comment: well, try checking (with debugger, ot System.out) the value of the calendar - whether it is really null, or a new Date

Comment: as i tested , the value is null in getters an d setters, i was surprised about that because i was expected to get a non null value...

Answer (score 0):

JSF does not validate null fields. JSF 2 however has the option to validate null's in order to be compliant with the bean validation framework.